# Jackson generate id for saved references

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

In my project, class `A` references class `B`.

When saving an `A` using Jackson, I want to keep the reference to `B`, which is also saved.

To do that, I have a field called "id" in the referenced class and use this annotation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope = ReferencedClass.class, generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
```

Doing this works fine when passing the id in the constructor, but I am creating an unknown number of `ReferencedClass`es.

Is there a way to make Jackson generate the id automatically?

And I wonder what the parameter `generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when using empty constructors and a proper @JsonTypeInfo if `B` is being extended.

I don't need `generateId()` anymore.

Using `generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class` generated an id, which is only present in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution that fit to this case, so in my main saveobject, I ended up using this code:

```
@JsonProperty private long generatedId = 0;

public long generateId() {
    return generatedId++;
}
```

Comment: be careful when you scale up your application, multiple nodes can make your ID collision

Comment: @KhuynhThànhChiLuyến Thanks for the advice! I am not creating many objects and it seems like if I would create an object every milisecond, I would not run out of ids in 100 years :)